# Apache2 server : many users can't acces (ipv4,ipv6)

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I made a server for a research project two days ago (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Apache2, PHP). I haven't set a domain name yet, so the webpage is only accessible via ip adress (in this case ipv6,inet 6addr at ppp0).

I asked a friend to try it, everything worked fine on her computer and mobile phone too. Later I asked some friends and colleagues to access the webpage but they were not able to do so. They got the 443 unreachable error message. My first friend was still able to access the webpage her computer and mobile phone. I run through some questions here and on other sites to solve this problem but nothing helped.

I asked the users to check their IP-s on https://www.whatismyip.com/. When using her ethernet and wifi at home, my first friend had ipv6 type IP address, she was able to access the site. The other users had ipv4 type address and they were not able to access my webpage. I asked my first friend to switch to the mobile internet provided by her telephone company. After this she wasn't able to access the site and she had ipv4 type IP address. After she switched back to her wifi she was able to access the page again.
What could be the cause of this strange problem? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Does the server have IPv4 address at all?

Comment: Could you please try to split your problem in smaller ones, so we can  provide proper help. E.g. can you access the server via ssh? Can you access the website on localhost?

Comment: It doesn't have IPv4 address. Could it be the problem? I can access it on localhost.

Comment: Insufficient IPv6 support seems likely to be the problem. You could add 'ipv6' tag and mention in title that it's IPv6-only to get people who know about ipv6 to notice this better. (I don't really know about this.)

Comment: This belongs on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server has only IPv6 and the user has only IPv4 then they won't be able to communicate. More and more clients have both IPv4 and IPv6 these days, but unfortunately there are also many clients left that only have IPv4.

If you want your server to be reachable by them then you'll need to make it reachable over IPv4 as well as IPv6. There are free services that help you do that (cloudflare comes to mind)